# data.json is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

How do I get data from my `Promise.all`?

I currenty get the error:

**Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: data.json is not a function
TypeError: data.json is not a function**

```
export function fetchEvents() {
    let pagesRequired = 0;
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        fetch(
            "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events?per_page=50&categories=107"
        )
            .then(response => {
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const apiPromises = [];
                pagesRequired = data.total_pages;

                for (let i = pagesRequired; i > 0; i--) {
                    apiPromises.push(
                        fetch(
                            "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events?per_page=50&categories=107&page=" +
                                i
                        )
                    );
                }
                Promise.all(apiPromises)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response;
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data.json());
                    });
            });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
for (let i = pagesRequired; i > 0; i--) {
  apiPromises.push(
    fetch(
      "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events?per_page=50&categories=107&page=" +
      i
    ).then(resp => resp.json())
  );
}
Promise.all(apiPromises)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

`apiPromises` should collect promises that resolves to the thing you ultimately need. Then do `Promise.all(apiPromises)` to get the actual data. Here is a [small demo with `fetch`](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7n582w9n7) to show how `Promise.all` API is working with `fetch`.

Answer (score 2):

Promise.all returns an array of results, if you are expecting `Response` object within this array you should first select it : `response[0].json()`.